# lauterbach t32-remote T32_Init() api returns -1[T32_ERR_COM_RECEIVE_FAIL]

Tags: python, remote-access, trace32, lauterbach

Using T32-remote api to automate test. Lauterbach is connected through Ethernet

config.t32:

```
RCL=NETASSIST
PACKLEN=1024
PORT=20000

; Environment variables
OS=
ID=T32
TMP=<temp_path>
SYS=C:\T32


; i.e. EtherNET
PBI=
NET                     
;TRACE32 HW
NODE=<IP>/<hostname>                ; hostname assigned to the TRACE32 device
CONNECTIONMODE=AUTOCONNECT

; Printer settings 
PRINTER=WINDOWS
```

Script:

```
self.t32_api.T32_Config(b"NODE=", b"localhost")
self.t32_api.T32_Config(b"PORT=", b"20000")
self.t32_api.T32_Config(b"PACKLEN=", b"1024")
self.t32_api.T32_Init()
```

Config returns 0 but T32_Init returns -1[Receiving API response failed].

for ethernet connection to T32, Am I missing some configuration?

Comment: The latest version of TRACE32 also includes a Python module which might save you a lot of headache. Version 1.0.0 will be released with the DVD 2020.09, but you can contact python-support@lauterbach.com to get a pre-release version.

Comment: You could try to verify that TRACE32 is configured correctly by using t32apicmd (<t32sys>/demo/api/capi/test).

Comment: @dev15 but <t32sys>/demo/api/capi/test is useful when connection is through USBwhat about through ethernet. Tried executing: python memaccess.py
output: Can't connect to TRACE32!

Comment: Whether the box is connected by USB or Ethernet shouldn't matter. You don't connect to the box, you connect to the GUI.

Comment: @dev15. So do you mean issue in GUI? As I am executing this remote api from remote system using IPaddress. I was wondering it could be some parameter value I am missing

Comment: If you are on a remote system (if your Python program runs on a different PC than the TRACE32 GUI) you need to set change `T32_Config(b"NODE=", b"localhost")` to `T32_Config(b"NODE=", b"<ip/nodename>")`. It doesn't matter how the box is connected, this is already handled by the `PBI=` setting in the configuration file.

Comment: Tried executing script again by modifying node in script. Getting same error from script but using GUI/t32strt.exe able to connect [manually].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After multiple experiments found that If we are executing from demo/python directory, T32_start and its instance need to keep it open. If it is open then script will execute without any error.

If node is given in config.t32, No need to add again in code "localHost" will work.